# How to launch unelevated exe from elevated AHK script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I'm trying to launch Spotify, if it's not running, by pressing the Play/Pause button on the keyboard.

I have this.

```
Media_Play_Pause::
Process, Exist, spotify.exe
if ErrorLevel
{
    Send {Media_Play_Pause}
}
else
{
    Run, Spotify
}
return
```

This works, but since my ahk is ran as admin, Spotify also runs as admin.
Why is this bad? because elevated Spotify doesn't show the media control buttons in the taskbar preview, and it creates a new icon on the taskbar separate from the pinned Spotify icon.

Is there any way to run Spotify as normal user and not as admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Shell to run the program for you.
[Here's](//autohotkey.com/board/topic/72812-run-as-standard-limited-user/?p=522235) one implementation, and [here's](//autohotkey.com/board/topic/72812-run-as-standard-limited-user/?p=725693) an other.
Don't have any opinions for which would be better, both seem to work for me.

Usage of either of the functions in your script would be:

```
Media_Play_Pause::
    Process, Exist, spotify.exe
    if (ErrorLevel)
        SendInput, {Media_Play_Pause}
    else
        ShellRun("Spotify") ; I don't have Spofify, so I didn't try using this short name for it. If it doesn't work, try to specify the full path of the exe
return

; copy paste the function here
```

Comment: Yes! This works, Thank you. Tried the first version and it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`RunAs`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RunAs.htm)

For example:

```
RunAs, UserName, UserPassword
Run, Spotify
```

Should run the Spotify as the User you have specified, which you could specify to be your own user profile [you need to replace UserName and UserPassword with the correct credentials in order for this to work]

If you are unsure of what your user name is, you can list all of them by using the `net user` command in command prompt.

Here is what your code would look like with this change:

```
Media_Play_Pause::
Process, Exist, spotify.exe
if ErrorLevel
{
    Send {Media_Play_Pause}
}
else
{
    RunAs, UserName, UserPassword ;Change these to be the correct values!
    Run, Spotify
}
return
```

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. If it does not, please let me know what I can do to improve it.

Comment: Wouldn't that also just run the program as administrator? Since I'm logged in and only use one account which is administrator.

Comment: I think that I should clarify what I mean. On Windows Computers, there is a separate "Administrator" account that is, by default, disabled on consumer computers. In other words, even if you only have created only one *user* account on your computer, you will still have this default Administrator account on the computer. You can verify this by opening a command prompt and using the command `net user`, which lists all of the user accounts on your computer.

Comment: Furthermore, if you created a User Account on your computer by linking it to a Windows account (which is the most common way of doing it), your UserName (that you would need to substitute into the AHK script above) will likely be different than the name it shows you when you log in to your computer. So, if there is only one user account on your computer, you can easily identify it within the list of users created by the `net user` command. If you want more clarification, sources, or etc, feel free to let me know! @DD3R

Comment: @DD3R More specifically addressing your question, the RunAs command changes which user is doing the action. If, as you mentioned, the AHK script is running as administrator, then the mentioned user is actually the default "Administrator" account. However, in order to "unelevate" the launch of Spotify, you would need to change the User that is running it to your standard user account that you created on the computer.

Comment: In other words:
Elevated = The user, "Administrator, which is usually disabled that comes shipped with Windows is running the program
Unelevated = The user account that you created and are referencing is running the program

Comment: Thank you for your help, I couldn't get RunAs to do what I wanted, but ShellRun, which was suggested by another user worked.

Comment: This will not work if the user's password is blank